# System.Net.Mail.Attachment file url contains a #

Tags: c#, .net, email, attachment

I am using System.Net.Mail.Attachment for email attachment.

```
 Attachment attachment = new Attachment (attachementFile);
```

But my attachementFile is from s3 file url and it contains #.
Therefor I got this error.
"The given path's format is not supported."

How can I fix this issue ?

Comment: Could you pleas clarify why you [read](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.attachment.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Net_Mail_Attachment__ctor_System_String_) "fileName - A String that contains a *file path* to use to create this attachment" as "fileName is URI"?

Comment: yes. attachementFile is a URL. It contains a #.

Comment: So you've read documentation which said you need to pass *file path* but disagreed with that and pass *URI* instead... I'm not sure how to help you in this case, sorry.